# ngx markdown syntax highlight C# not highlighting

Tags: angular, markdown

I included ngx-markdown in my angular project. the markdown in image 1 gets translated into the image 2 output. image 3 shows my included scripts for syntaxhighlighting for c#. somehow i dont get the hightlighting working. i followed the docs in the link below. but it seems i missed some point to get it working. did anyone run into this problem earilier and may be able to help me out on this one?

https://prnt.sc/xib37z (Image 1- markdown content)

https://prnt.sc/xib6fj (Image 2- rendered markdown)

https://prnt.sc/xib73y (Image 3- angular.json(styles and scripts))

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown